# session on CodeIgniter 3, userdata or not?

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I'm trying to following a youtube tuts for make a login system on CodeIgniter.
I was pretty new on php framework and I choose CI for its semplicity.
So I have an array where I need to store session data:

```
$data = array('email' => $this->input->post('email'),
            is_logged_in' => true);
```

the tutorial use userdata(); function with

```
    $this->session->userdata($data);
```

but when he try to print de session array do:

```
    print_r($this->session->all_userdata($data));
```

alluserdata(); is deprecated, so I read the doc, and I found out that userdata is a legacy function.
I want to learn what I write so I try to modernize the code to be updated and clean for CI3.

is use userdata(); good for CI3? or I have to use $_SESSION[]? or $this->session?

The problems is that if I try to use

$this->session->data

and than:

```
print_r($this->session->data);
```

I have nothing in output.
I just want to output data array in session so I can understand if it's working.
Thank you in advance

**EDIT**
if i use set_userdata() for set session and just print_r($this->session->userdata()); for print session all I have is:

```
    Array
(
    [__ci_last_regenerate] => 1453313633
    [email] => admin@admin.com
    [is_logged_in] => 1
)
```

and not info about browser, time ecc...is that normal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Codignitor 3 you can get values from **$this->session** obejct as:

```
//Normal PHP    
$name = $_SESSION['name'];    

// IN Ci:    
$name = $this->session->name    

// you can also get by
$name = $this->session->userdata('name');
```

**And whats wrong with your code?**

You are using session object as

```
$this->session->data
```

This should be

```
$this->session->userdata
```

> is use userdata(); good for CI3? or I have to use _SESSION[]?

For this, yes it's better to use framework libaray becuase you can manage and reuse your code easily.

Comment: With regard to `userdata()` vs `$_SESSION[]`: The main advantage of using `$this->session->userdata('item');` is that the function takes care of checking that 'item' is a valid key. The same is true for the magic getters (ie `$item = $this->session->item;`).  All of these functions, and many others in the sessions library are working directly with the `$_SESSION` array. So there is nothing wrong with using `$_SESSION` directly.

Comment: thank you I will you userdata() then i think is more readable than use just the magic getter...

Answer (score 3):

Set session data

```
$newdata = array('email' => $email, 'is_logged_in' => true);
$this->session->set_userdata($newdata);
```

Get session data

```
$email = $this->session->userdata('email');
$is_logged_in = $this->session->userdata('is_logged_in');
```

OR

```
$dataArray = $this->session->userdata();
```

Comment: thank you as I said I will use userdata() instead of magic getter, if they are equal, i think userdata(); is more readable then just $this->session->item